# "coke adds life", is the sentence grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammar

"coke adds life" is (maybe "was") a famous advertising slogan.

[image]

I guess I understand the meaning:

> Coca-Cola makes your life better.

However, it does not seem to fit anyone in the following meanings.

> v. add·ed, add·ing, adds
>
> v.tr.
>
> 1. To join or combine (numbers) through addition: If you add 5 and 10 and 17, the result is 32. If you add 6 to 8, you get 14.
> 2. To join or unite so as to increase in size, quantity, quality, or scope: added 12 inches to the deck; flowers that added beauty to the
>      dinner table.
> 3. To say or write further.
>
> v.intr.
>
> 1. To find a sum in arithmetic.
>
> 2.
>
> a. To constitute an addition: an exploit that will add to her
>   reputation.
>
> b. To create or make an addition: gradually added to my meager
>   savings.

[source](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=add)

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many of your questions ask for "The rules/conventions"  I'm never quite sure what you mean by this.  In this question it is a matter of "meaning".  There is no general rule or convention. Do you just add this phrase to all your questions?

Comment: @JamesK Thank you. Not all of them, most of them. It may be some stated grammar or some kind of pattern. For example, `some kind of noun`, should the "noun" be plural form or singular form, it might be a grammar rule in textbook, though people tend to use one more commonly than other choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "life" is often used as a synonym for energy, vitality, liveliness, vivacity, spirit, etc. We often say that a happy, energetic person is "full of life." If you think of "life" in this way, almost as a substance or magic potion, then you can talk about things having life, giving life, or adding life. For example, Photoshop can "add life" to your photos. People select decor that "adds life" to their homes.

So, Coke's advertising slogan doesn't quite mean, "Coke makes your life better," it means "Coke adds energy/vitality/liveliness/spirit to your life."

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at the wrong word to explain this advertising slogan. In addition to its basic meaning, the word "life" has this meaning:
[American Heritage Dictionary "life"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=life)

b. Liveliness or vitality; animation: *a face that is full of life.*

With that meaning, the sense of "add" as in the transitive sense 2 above fits.

Answer (score 0):

Advertising slogans do not have to be grammatically correct, but this one is. It is an example of meaning 1.2 'to join so as to increase quantity, quality': Coke joins your life to add extra 'life', or Coke adds extra life to your existing life.